# .htaccess file breaks php image paths

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess, path

I changed some of the urls into a more readable format using .htaccess file, however when I checked the pages, everything got broken. Than I started to change all of the javascript paths(css and other files) into this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/mg_com_tr/css/sss.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/mg_com_tr/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">   </script>
```

at the beggining of all the urls, I added;

```
http://localhost/mg_com_tr/
```

and that seemed to fix some of the major issues.
But when it comes to do the same thing to my php files things didn't go as smooth.`

For example this is the path to my image gallery files;

```
$directory = '../Panel/products/_images/'.$row['id'].'/';
```

I tried adding  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] at the beggining, but that didn't work. I also tried it like I did it with the javascript files by adding

```
 http://localhost/mg_com_tr/
```

at the beggining, but that didn't also work either.

EDIT:

changing the base href solved the issue.

```
<BASE href="http://localhost/mg_com_tr/index.php">
```

The thing is I still don't know why or how it worked.

Comment: Use `<base href=>` or a `RewriteCond` for relocating img/css resources. As for your PHP issues, that sounds like confusion between server-relative and web-paths still. You need to concretise your issues / error messages / html / paths.

Comment: Show us your htaccess please.

Comment: Please show your .htaccess